# control what applications go on screen

Tags: gui, window-manager, display-manager

For a project, I need to be able to decide what applications appear on the screen. I want it to be controllable with basic console commands I could run from a program. I will only be showing one full-screen application at a time. Ideally it would auto default to a menu application if the currently visible application crashed or stoped.

Comment: That may depend on the desktop environment. Please post your Ubuntu release and version.

Comment: When on xorg, look at `wmctrl` and `xdotool` as command line tools that allow to control windows.